# Optimizing Dijkstra for fixed number of weights

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Let $G=(V,E)$ be our directed graph with edgeweigths
$c\colon E \rightarrow \Bbb{Q}_{\geq 0}$.
Now modifiy Dijkstra's algorithm, such that the algorithm solves instances with only a constant number of unique edge weights in linear time. In other words, if $|\{c_e \mid e\in E\}| =: C$ is independent of $|V|$ and $|E|$, the runtime of Dijkstra's algorithm can be improved.

Can anyone help me with that problem?

Answer (score 0):

If all edges have the same weight, then this is essentially the same as they have a unit weight. In such case you may use BSF instead of Dijkstra's algorithm.

Similar idea is useful for more than one weight. Suppose that $c(e) \in \{\,c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_k\,\}$ for all $e \in E$ and some constant $k$. In Dijkstra's algorithm we every time among all non-considered vertices take a vertex $v$ with the least distance bound $\ell(v)$. And consider this vertex $v$, making relaxation along all outgoing arcs. If $v$ is not a starting vertex, then somewhen earlier we improved its distance bound making relaxation along some incoming edge $e$.

The essential point is that $c(e)$ is one of $k$ possible values and, like in BFS, and if a vertex $u$ is considered before a vertex $v$ and they have outgoing arcs of the same weight $c$, then every end $x$ of arc of weight $c$ outgoing from the vertex $u$ gets distance bound $\ell(x) = d(u) + c$ which is less then or equal to the distance bound $\ell(y) = d(v) + c$ for every end $y$ of arc of weight $c$ outgoing from the vertex $v$. Therefore we can use $k$ usual queues $q_1, q_2, \ldots, q_k$, one for each of $c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_k$. Then successful relaxation along an edge $(v, y)$ of weight $c_i$ implies pushing the vertex $y$ into $q_i$. A vertex should not be pushed into the same queue twice, however this is not obligatory. But do not consider the same vertex twice, even if it comes from different queues, and this is more essential. Note that already considered vertex should not stay at the front of any other queue, otherwise it will be uselessly compared to other vertices.

Thus each relaxation takes $\mathrm O(1)$ of time. To find a non-considered vertex with the least distance bound we should check fronts of all queues. This takes $\mathrm O(k) = \mathrm O(1)$ of time since $k$ is a constant. (Dealing with the starting vertex we just know in advance that it has the least distance bound, however we may just push it into any queue.) So the total time is $\mathrm O(n + m)$, where $n$ is the number of vertices and $m$ is the number of arcs, since we select a new vertex to consider up to $n$ times and make up to $m$ relaxations. On the other hand it could be more informative to write the total time as $\mathrm O(kn + m)$ if $k$ is not much less than $m / n$. Also it gives understanding that for $n$ and $m$ such that $\frac{m \log_2 n}{n} < k$ it may be better to use usual variation of Dijkstra's algorithm based on priority queue and proposed by Johnson.